# Incorrect proof of open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering if this proof of the open mapping theorem works; my hunch is that it is incorrect since many similar proofs use Rouche's theorem.

Let $f\colon D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and $U\subset D$ be an open set. Then pick some $z_0\in D$. Using isolated zero theorem, we can pick some Jordan curve $\gamma\colon [0,1]\rightarrow U$ around $z_0$ that is fully contained in $U$ where $\gamma(t)\neq f(z_0)$ for all $t$.

We can now consider the image $f(\gamma(t))-f(z_0)$. It is a curve in $\mathbb{C}$ that has some positive winding number around $0$. But now we can consider a small ball of radius $\delta$ around $f(z_0)$ where $\delta$ is strictly less than the distance between the curve $f(\gamma(t))-f(z_0)$ and $0$; this is possible by compatcness of the curve. But now, if we pick any $f(z_0)+h\in B(f(z_0),\delta)$, we see that
$f(\gamma(t))-(f(z_0)+h)$ also has a positive winding number around $0$, as all this has done is shifted the curve $f(\gamma(t))-f(z_0)$ by an amount small enough where it would not intersect $0$. The argument principle then implies the existence of some $z$ in the interior of $\gamma$ such that $f(z)=f(z_0)+h$.

Comment: The proof of Rouche's theorem is through winding numbers, so it wouldn't be surprising if this works. BTW, to find the curve, you can just use the fact that $z_0$ has some open ball contained in $U$, therefore it contains a closed ball, so your curve can picked to be on the circumference of that ball.

Comment: This is pretty much the proof from Ahlfors book so it is a classic one